# How to set array as column to build HTML table using Ajax from Json?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, html-table

I have JSON data as follows:

```
{
  "produk": [
    {
      "id": "6",
      "stock": {
        "M": "2",
        "S": "3",
        "L": "9"
      },
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

I want to display the JSON data in a table as follows:

[image: table from JSON data]

But I have a problem with the "stock" column. I have difficulties in classifying stock data.
Please help the data from JSON to be the appropriate table that I expect.

Comment: I think this is nothing about `ajax`..

Comment: I want make table using ajax with data from json like my example.

Comment: ok, so what's the detail of `problem with stock column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate this by having a table prebuilt and having your JSON variable availiable.

```js
produk = {
  "produk": [
    {
      "id": "6",
      "stock": {
        "M": "2",
        "S": "3",
        "L": "9"
      }
    }
  ]
}["produk"][0];

$(".id").html(produk.id);
$(".M").html(produk.stock.M);
$(".S").html(produk.stock.S);
$(".L").html(produk.stock.L);
```

```css
td,tr,table {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsTable">
  <tr><td rowspan="2">ID</td><td colspan="3" data-id="id">Stock</td></tr>
  <tr><td>S</td><td>M</td><td>L</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="id">id</td><td class="S">S</td><td class="M">M</td><td class="L">L</td></tr>
</table>
```